# Find the max projection angle so that distance from point of projection always increases

Tags: kinematics, projectile

We want to launch a projectile from the surface of earth so that its distance from the point of projection is always increasing. What is the maximum angle of projection for which this is possible?

One way to visualize this would be that there should not be a component of velocity opposite to the position vector of the particle, the point of projection being the origin, at all times of motion.

So following this line of thought I wrote :

$$\overrightarrow v \cdot \overrightarrow r > 0$$

Which did not yield a very nice expression in the angle $\theta$.

There should be better methods, as is often the case with physics, please suggest some of them.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "point of projection is always increasing"? Are you simply looking for the angle of projection which yields the maximum range? In that case you will most definitely find your answer here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_of_a_projectile

Comment: Hi Shubham. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Comment: No, my question is different. Suppose we launch a projectile at a very steep angle. During its motion, the distance from point of projection( that would simply be the magnitude of its displacement at that time), would increase till a certain time and  then start decreasing. You can easily see this by drawing the path and drawing straight lines between point of projection different points on its path, a downward parabola.

Comment: @Qmechanic, this is actually a homework question from my physics book. Yes, I have read the SE policy on homework like questions. Even I do not expect  a full solution.

Comment: @Shubham That statement makes no sense whatsoever, so you're saying the projectile turns back on itself? What you're describing can only make sense if you're considering the vertical displacement of the projectile (maximum height).

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot bring a diagram. Consider again a projectile thrown such that its maximum height is more than its range, say twice or thrice of it. Take O as the point of projection H be the point at max height and R be the point where it finally returns to the ground. Now compare the distances OH and OR. The former is found to be significantly greater, which would mean at some point P of the path, the distance OP starts decreasing(for steep angles of projection).

Comment: @phonon: for angles greater than 45 degrees, the projectile will go higher than it goes further.

Comment: It seems to me that you dot product approach is the right one. Why don't you show the "not very nice expression" you end up with...  Maybe you made a simple mistake?

Comment: @KyleKanos Yes, right, of course, but the way Shubham was posing the problem initially suggested that the projectile at some point "turned back" on its horizontal trajectory, this is why I wrote all of that in my previous comment.

Comment: Another way to look at this - the "limit" trajectory is the one where the path of the projectile is at right angles to the vector from the origin to the vector.

Comment: @Floris, Yes that is a very nice approach. My physics teacher used the same to solve the problem. "You just have to draw a triangle", he had said, and I still don't get it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The equations of motions for a projectile are,

$$
x(t) = v_0 \cos(\theta)t,
$$

$$
y(t) = -\frac{1}{2}gt^2+v_0 \sin(\theta)t.
$$

Therefore the distance from the point of projection is,

$$
r(t)=\sqrt{x^2(t)+y^2(t)}.
$$

Since you want the distance from the point of projection is always increasing, we must have,

$$
\frac{dr(t)}{dt} > 0.
$$

By substituting $r(t)$, $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ in above equation, after some straightforward calculation you can easily obtain,

$$
\frac{dr(t)}{dt} = \frac{g^2 t^2 - 3 g t v_0 \sin(\theta) + 2 v_0^2}{\sqrt{g^2 t^2-4 g t v_0 \sin(\theta) + 4 v_0^2}}.
$$

Moreover, we know that if $a>0$, and $\Delta=b^2-4ac < 0$, then $at^2+bt+c > 0$ for all $t$. Therefore, we must have,

$$
a = g^2 > 0,
$$

$$
\Delta = g^2 v_0^2 \left(9 \sin^2(\theta) - 8\right) < 0,
$$

which results in

$$
\sin(\theta)<\sqrt{\frac{8}{9}} \to \theta < \sin^{-1}\left(\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3}\right) \approx 70.5288°
$$

Comment: I was missing just the last part, this was the same not so nice expression I had arrived at(Initially I had tried this approach). Just did not know how to proceed.

Answer (score 6):

Following up on my comment here is the (slightly simpler) math to compute this directly from the fact that product of gradients of two lines at right angles is -1:

[image]
[image]

Comment: That's exactly how my teacher solved it! This approach  looks nicer from a physicist's perspective.

Comment: it is very good *assuming* such a trajectory exists. But conveniently, the values for the angle and t are within the allowed range so it works. The method can't be extended if it just happened that such a trajectory does not exist, because we can't make a relationship between angle from the normal and velocity using the cross product because the cross product only tells you how close they are to right angles, not how large the difference between angles is

Comment: sorry if that didn't make sense

Comment: I am using the dot product not the cross product. Yes if there is no solution there is no solution... I don't understand your comment sorry.

Comment: If you never get to right angle, then the point where the projectile lands is the furthest point... that is not a solution to the above equation but it would be easy enough to find.

Comment: Another way to look at this - the "limit" trajectory is the one where the path of the projectile is at right angles to the vector from the origin to the vector. Why are we using this condition?  I don't get it

Comment: @Zerix when it is at right angles the distance to the origin is not changing. That means you are neither getting closer nor further... you are at the limit.

Comment: Okay. That makes sense

Comment: One last question. How to check beyond this angle  the distance is increasing or decreasing. I mean there could be two cases after the limit, right!

Comment: @Zerix usually you can figure this out with a simple diagram. For the simple case given it is obvious the curvature is the path is towards the origin.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This is the time where pv is perpendicular to velocity and if this time exists then distance of projectile from point of projection will not increase.
So take discriminant negative to vanish possibility of this time

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can indeed solve it simply with vectors. The only thing to keep in mind is replacing correctly dot product of initial velocity and gravitational acceleration.

Comment: Please use MathJaX for equations on this site;  images are less accessible for screen readers and are not searchable.  [Here's a tutorial on how to do so.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)